# Process All Windows Messages Generated By A Compact Framework Application

Tags: compact-framework, message-queue, subclassing

Hoepfully someone can shed some light on a problem - I am trying to listen to\intercept all windows messages generated by an application and dispose of certain types, for example Notify or Gesture messages.

I have been reading articals on how to do this using the Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms.MessageWindow and creating a class which inherits this, overrides the WndProc method but I have been unalbe to get this start listening\watching the message queue automatically when the application starts.

I know it is possible to do this with the OpenNetCF framework and the Application2 namespace however I would prefer not to use 3rd party software at the moment - no offence to the OpenNetCF guys.

Hopefully this makes sense. Also, i am using C#2.0 and Windows Mobile 6.5.

Thanks for your help,

Morris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution, then, is pretty simple - all you have to do is spend your time duplicating what the Smart Device Framework code is doing.

You need to create your own message pump via P/Invokes to [GetMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa921213.aspx), [TranslateMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa931781.aspx) and [DispatchMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa920750.aspx) (it will look just like [it does in C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows)).  Use this pump instead of calling Application.Run (so there can be no calls to Application.Run in your application).

Inside that new message pump insert your filtering logic.

Comment: OpenNETCF lets you create custom filters as well, right? Man you already got a whole bunch of really sweet tech there. 
Am I right in understanding that the professional license gives you access to the source too?

Comment: Thanks for the help - decided to do the sensible thing and use the OpenNetCF.

Thanks again!